# Run-time error '1004': Application-defined or object-defined error while running below code

Tags: vba, excel

When autofiltering and there is no data  or only one type of data i am getting error on line

```
 Set rang = rang.Resize(rang.Rows.Count - 1)
```

in below code i have data from only criteria2

```
Dim rang As Range
    Set sh = Worksheets("ExampleSheet")
           sh.Select
        Range("A1").Select
        Selection.AutoFilter
        sh.UsedRange.AutoFilter Field:=10, Criteria1:= _
            "=*Criteria1*", VisibleDropDown:=False
        Set rang = sh.UsedRange.Offset(1, 0)
        Set rang = rang.Resize(rang.Rows.Count - 1)
        On Error Resume Next
        Set rang = rang.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
        If Err.Number = 0 Then
        rang.Select
        rang.Copy
        Sheets("Criteria2").Select
        Range("A1").Select
          ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste
          sh.Select
        Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
        End If
        On Error GoTo 0

       sh.Cells.AutoFilter
        Application.CutCopyMode = False



           sh.Select
        Range("A1").Select
        Selection.AutoFilter
        sh.UsedRange.AutoFilter Field:=10, Criteria1:= _
            "=*Criteria2*", VisibleDropDown:=False
        Set rang = sh.UsedRange.Offset(1, 0)
        Set rang = rang.Resize(rang.Rows.Count - 1)
        On Error Resume Next
        Set rang = rang.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
        If Err.Number = 0 Then
        rang.Select
        rang.Copy
        Sheets("Criteria2").Select
        Range("A1").Select
          ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste
          sh.Select
        Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
        End If
        On Error GoTo 0

      sh.Cells.AutoFilter
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
```

Comment: Error is on *which line* ?

Comment: in this line  Set rang = rang.Resize(rang.Rows.Count - 1)

Comment: Do that before the autofilter step (assuming UsedRange is always >1 row)

Comment: Did it still not working. also i have place this code twice above there is another criteria

Comment: Are you adding the filters cumulatively, or resetting between each filter?

Comment: But In the page it got autofiltered and copied to the other sheet but the program is not proceeding

Comment: the same code above is repeated twice

Comment: try this: `Set rang = rang.Resize(rang.Rows.Count - 1, rang.Columns.Count)`. It's too late for me to dig into it but this may help you.

Comment: Nope not working masoud

Comment: What is Rang.address just before the line of code that causes the error?

Comment: I dint understand you Rich Holton

Comment: I have made some changes in question check now

Comment: The address property of a Range object is a string, something like "A2:B6" that describes the cells the Range includes. So, what does rang.address look like just before the statement that throws the error? A related question is, what is rang.Rows.Count? If it's 1, then you will get an error (trying to resize to 0).

Comment: OK ill try this too

Comment: Thanks Rich i have set rngcopy = Nothing for  the below answer tim gave as the datatype range value wont take as 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Sub CopyCopy()

    Dim rngUsed As Range, rngCopy As Range
    Dim sht As Worksheet

    Set sht = Sheets("All Data")


    sht.Range("A1").AutoFilter '<<clear any previous filtering
    Set rngUsed = sht.Range("A1").CurrentRegion

    rngUsed.AutoFilter Field:=10, Criteria1:= _
        "=*Criteria2*", VisibleDropDown:=False

    On Error Resume Next
    With rngUsed.Offset(1, 0).Resize(rngUsed.Rows.Count - 1)
        'any visisble rows?
        Set rngCopy = .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    End With
    On Error GoTo 0

    If Not rngCopy Is Nothing Then
        rngCopy.Copy Sheets("Criteria2").Range("A2")
        rngCopy.Delete Shift:=xlUp
        Set rngCopy = Nothing '<<< clear range variable
    End If
    sht.Range("A1").AutoFilter '<<clear any filtering

    'repeat with other criteria or create a loop

End Sub
```

Comment: This works , now trying to repeat , how do i loop for all 22 different criterias

Comment: Should i use advanced criteria method?, but i dont have all the criterias so for now i have copy the remaining data to one sheet

Comment: Thanks Tim .This method is working even if i am repeating for multiple criteria , the only change i did is set rngcopy = Nothing ,after each criteria, but if i set it as rngcopy= nothing will the rangcopy value be nothing or empty range(Nothing)

Comment: Sorry yes I forgot to add that line resetting `rngCopy to `Nothing`

Comment: Ah 'to nothing'  i did it as = nothing , thanks for your help

Comment: No that's just my bad formatting you should `Set rngCopy = Nothing`